# SQL Query to Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I was asked at work to switch from SQL Server to Mongo DB.

I am doing good understanding the no-sql concept, but I am having a hard time understanding a few things.

The current application works in Angular 10. This application calls a set of .NET APIs to query the SQL Server database and returns all needed Json files for the application to operate.

My concern is regarding specific queries I perform today at the server side, as this one:

```
WITH IH AS (SELECT        SponsorPL, plid
                           FROM            dbo.PL
                           WHERE        (plid = 154)
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT        A.SponsorPL, A.plid
                           FROM            dbo.PL AS A INNER JOIN
                                                    IH AS B ON B.SponsorPL = A.plid)
    SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT IH_1.plid, PL_1.userid
     FROM            IH AS IH_1 INNER JOIN
                              dbo.PL AS PL_1 ON IH_1.plid = PL_1.plid
     WHERE        (IH_1.plid <> 154)
```

This particular recursive query retrieves, for user 154, his entire upline (his sponsor) and returns the records as on the attached image.

[image]

Can these types of queries be done on MongoDB?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at MongoDB’s aggregation framework. It allows more complex queries. There are excellent tutorials on the MongoDB website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB as noSQL distributed document store differs significantly from RDBMS SQL databases  , you need in general to denormalize the relational model and transform it to document model avoiding such type of join queries as much as possible , in case you cannot avoid it, you can still use aggregation / $lookup to achieve similar results...